# Shift Switcher change on release

Tags: compiz, workspace-switcher

I want to make Shift Switcher to select window on release, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

I currently have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> configure for Next Window in Workspace, so I press it and move windows, but when I release, I have to press Enter or Shift to get to the window. This isnt the normal behaviour with the default key for Previous Window, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, which changes to the selected window on release.

How can achieve this, or is it a bug?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution.

My Super key is also used for the launcher in Unity and that's having some kind of conflict.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped, and even though the answer was simple, it's important for those who rely on window switching for productivity. Thanks!